# Column names and types of pandas.Dataframe with mypy or other static way?

Tags: python, pandas, static-analysis, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function `func` which accepts a `pandas.Dataframe`, The dataframe must have the columns: `'col_foo', 'col_bar'` and their types must be `pd.Timestamp, np.integer` for `func` to no fail.

how would I ensure these columns exist in a static manner?

---

I can do something like this:

```py
def func(df: pd.Dataframe):
    cols_struct = {'col_foo': pd.Timestamp, 'col_bar': np.integer}
    # also check the columns types here
    if not set(df.columns).issuperset(cols_struct.keys()):
        raise ValueError('the dataframe must be structured like', cols_struct)
```

Or use an existing library and do it neatly with a decorator.

However I want my code to fail during `mypy` static type check and not during runtime, How would I type hint `func`?